# MVC 4 Use Radio button to select different output

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using a dropdownlist to make a different selections.

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, Model.PossibleIds)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
```

The following code will show a dropdown of Ids, 1,2,3,4,5.
When I select 1 in the dropdown, there's a text that display "You have selected 1", and so on.

Now I have to change the following dropdown to Radio button

```
@foreach(var ids in Model.Possibleids)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Id, Model.PossibleId)@ids.Text
}
```

I want the same functionality with the radio button,
when I select Radio button number 1, I want a text that display "You have selected 1"
when I select Radio button number 2,  I want a text that display "You have selected 2" and so on. What changes do I have to make to my Javascript to make this happen?
My Current Jquery Script ( According to Dropdown, I changed the Val to Onclick or checked events but nothing worked)

```
(function ($) {
    $('#Id').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 1) {
            $('.1-option').hide();
            $('.2-option').show();
            $('.3-option').hide();
            $('.4-option').hide();
            $('.5-option').hide();

        } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
            $('.1-option').show();
            $('.2-option').show();
            $('.3-option').hide();
            $('.4-option').hide();
            $('.5-option').show();
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == 3) {
            $('.1-option').hide();
            $('.2-option').hide();
            $('.3-option').hide();
            $('.4-option').show();
            $('.5-option').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your JavaScript I can only assume you're using jQuery. If so, then the following will get you what you need.

```
var selectedVal = $("input[type='radio'][name='Id']:checked");
if (selectedVal.length > 0) {
    $('#spanDisplayValue').text(selectedVal);
}
```

Edit to address specific code. I think the code above is a much more efficient way to accomplish your goal, but I left the core logic the same to give you an example.

```
(function ($) {
    $("input[name=Id]:radio").change(function () {
    var selectedVal = $("input[type='radio'][name='Id']:checked");
    if (selectedVal == 1) {
        $('.1-option').hide();
        $('.2-option').show();
        $('.3-option').hide();
        $('.4-option').hide();
        $('.5-option').hide();

    } else if (selectedVal == 2) {
        $('.1-option').show();
        $('.2-option').show();
        $('.3-option').hide();
        $('.4-option').hide();
        $('.5-option').show();
    }
    else if (selectedVal == 3) {
        $('.1-option').hide();
        $('.2-option').hide();
        $('.3-option').hide();
        $('.4-option').show();
        $('.5-option').hide();
```

Comment: Could you please help me modifying the jQuery above for Radio button?

Comment: Hi, Thank You for your help. I really appreciate it. The Jquery script I have mentioned here exactly matches to my needs. I did the changes mentioned by you. But there is no luck script is not working. The old script works well with the Dropdown but the new script is not working. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: (

    function ($) {
        $("input[name=Id]:radio").change(function () {
            var selectedVal = $("input[type='radio'][name='Id']:checked").val();
            if (selectedVal == 1) {

    
            } else if (selectedVal == 2) {
                $('.1-option').show();
                $('.2-option').show();
                $('.3-option').hide();
                $('.4-option').hide();
                $('.5-option').show();

Comment: You need to verify that the name of the HTML elements that get rendered are the same across the radio buttons.